# Javascript error in HTML output from systrace, any ideas?

Tags: android, debugging

When I run systrace from DDMS (on Windows) the html file that is produced contains a javascript error that is preventing the results from being seen in a browser.  The data exists in the html file, but it is very difficult to use without viewing it in a browser.  Any ideas on what is wrong?  I don't think I should have to fix the javascript, there must be something up with systrace/adt/ddms IMO, I just can't figure out what.

Looks like this has been reported already, see [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?q=systrace&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&id=57135).

Here's the error (from Chrome):

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

And here's the javascript where the error is coming from:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  if (!linuxPerfData)
    return;
  var m = new tracing.model(linuxPerfData); //This line throws the exception.
  var timelineViewEl = document.querySelector('.view');
  tracing.ui.decorate(timelineViewEl, tracing.TimelineView);
  timelineViewEl.model = m;
  timelineViewEl.tabIndex = 1;
  timelineViewEl.timeline.focusElement = timelineViewEl;
});
```